# Finding nth term application problem

Tags: combinatorics

I was given this question class today and I wasn't quite sure how to solve it

"There are $10$ computers all connected with a cable to each other computer"

1) How many wires are there?

2) How many cables will there be with $20$ computers?

3) How can you find the nth number of cables?

Comment: As a general rule of thumb, if you're posting homework problems, it's a good idea to include any attempts at a solution you've made.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**:

If the first computer has a cable connected to each of the other nine, then there are $9$ cables for the first computer. Now the second computer needs a cable to every computer **BUT** the one it is already connected to. Do this for all the computers... You should see a pattern that you can apply to $n$ computers.

Answer (score 0):

Two ways of looking at this problem:

1. You can just start to count all the cables. You know the first computer is connected to $n-1$ other computers, giving you $n-1$ cables. The second computer has $n-1$ connections, but you already counted the connection between $1$ and $2$, so that makes $n-2$ new cables. The third computer gives you $n-3$ new cables and so on until the last computer gives $0$ new cables. The total number of cables is then $$1+2+3+\dots + n-1.$$ There exists a shorter way of writing this sum, of course.
2. You can look at each cable as defining a pair of computers. The number of cables is then equal to the number of all pairs of computer. You can get each pair by *choosing* two computers out of $n$. How many ways are there to choose $2$ elements out of a set of $n$?

Answer (score 0):

When each computer is connected with every other computer, it is technically called **mesh topology.**

The image below shows the mesh topology for 5 systems.

[image]

They are connected in $^5C_2$ ways. Similarly, 10 computers can be connected in $^{10} C_2$ ways. And the solution of the remaining problems follow.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT:**

You can see the computers as the corners of a polygon. You can used the following formula to determine, how many diagonals (cables) will go out of a corner (computer):

$$
\text{cables of }n\text{ computers}=\frac{n(n-3)}{2}
$$